# Combinatorics wording

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

I'm having trouble associating symbols in a combinatorics problem.  I want to say I'm taking a product over the possible subsets resulting from a choice of $k$ objects from $n$.

For example, say I have 3 individuals $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and I select 2 of them. That can give me:

$\{1, 2\}$ or $\{1, 3\}$ or $\{2, 3\}$

I perform the following operation:

$f(1)f(2)g(3) + f(1)f(3)g(2) + f(2)f(3)g(1)$

How can I express this using $\prod$ and $\sum$?

Comment: You should be much clearer in your statement of the problem.  What is $f$, and why would you sum those products?

Comment: Hmm...I was hoping not to get into that. The actual functions are a bit messy. Can we not just say that $f$ and $g$ are each a function of one variable, which is the identity of the individual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want $$\sum _{X\in \binom{[3]}{2}}\prod _{y\in [3]\setminus X}g(y)\prod _{x\in X}f(x).$$
Here the notation is $[n]=\{1,2,\cdots , n\}$ and $\binom{[n]}{k}=\{X\subseteq [n]:|X|=k\}.$

Comment: Does that choose function work still if I don't have $\{1, 2, 3\}$ but instead have, for example $\{3, 10, 15\}$? Basically do the elements themselves matter?

Comment: Nop, you just put the set that you want in the top, as $\binom{\{3,10,15\}}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

I have seen $f(1)f(2)g(3)+$cyclic for this, where the $+$cyclic indicates you cyclically rotate the arguments.  It would be easier to see if you wrote the second term $f(3)f(1)g(2)$

Comment: Thanks Ross, but I was specifically looking for sum and product notation.